# Who should own /var/log and /var/tmp

Tags: permissions

I was playing around with some scripts I have written and I might have changed their owner to root, though I am not sure. Who should be the owner of these folders ?

Comment: obviously root!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both should be owned by root, the group for `/var/log` should be `syslog`, and it should be world-writable.

Comment: What does world-editable mean? I am seeing see `drwxr-xr-x` (755) so only root can write...

Answer (score 5):

This is total `/var/`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 jul 19 07:56 backups
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root     4096 mrt 29 07:51 cache
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 jul 19 07:35 crash
drwxr-xr-x 72 root root     4096 jul 19 10:14 lib
drwxrwsr-x  2 root staff    4096 feb 27 19:33 local
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        9 mrt 29 07:47 lock -> /run/lock
drwxrwxr-x 15 root syslog   4096 jul 19 07:56 log
drwxrwsr-x  2 root mail     4096 mrt 20 08:31 mail
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 mrt 20 08:37 metrics
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 mrt 20 08:31 opt
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        4 mrt 29 07:47 run -> /run
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root     4096 mrt 20 08:35 spool
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root     4096 jul 19 13:52 tmp
```

Have fun

Comment: `chown -R root:syslog /var/log/nginx` -> `chown: invalid group: ‘root:syslog’` CentOS 7.7

Comment: CentOS is not Ubuntu. We have a syslog group. They don't.

Answer (score 1):

I also totally screwed all ownerships and groups up in `/var/log`. Since I have have a separate 21.04 Ubuntu, it allowed me to determine what they should be:

```
root   root      104003 Feb  1  2021 bootstrap.log
syslog adm            0 Aug 22 00:00 mail.err
root   root         573 Aug 25 21:54 fontconfig.log
root   adm            0 Sep  3 00:00 apport.log
root   root         162 Sep  9 15:25 alternatives.log
root   root       32064 Sep 13 17:30 faillog
syslog adm       109207 Sep 16 16:32 cloud-init-output.log
syslog adm      1943745 Sep 16 16:32 cloud-init.log
root   root       38778 Sep 16 19:03 dpkg.log
root   adm       764861 Sep 16 21:03 dmesg
root   root        6370 Sep 17 15:27 ubuntu-advantage.log
root   utmp     2783616 Sep 17 19:59 btmp
root   utmp      202752 Sep 17 20:06 wtmp
root   utmp      292584 Sep 17 20:06 lastlog
syslog adm          877 Sep 17 20:42 mail.log
syslog adm          977 Sep 17 20:48 auth.log
syslog adm        43183 Sep 17 20:50 ufw.log
syslog adm       422976 Sep 17 20:50 syslog
syslog adm        57150 Sep 17 20:50 kern.log
```

Comment: Personally I disagree with the "First Answer" reviewer -- Reading the question, this is useful information.  It just needed some formatting which I've submitted as an edit.  It may be late, but it will likely be useful to someone else looking for the answer in the future.